# What can my device administrator see when I am connected to a private WiFi?

Tags: privacy, administration

I use a device that has access to things like incognito mode. However, it warns me that the device administrator can see what I do even when in incognito. I know that this is true when connected to an administrated WiFi, but, when I’m home and on a private WiFi, can the administrator still see what I do? (No forced VPN on my device)

Edit: Assume I am in incognito mode where the history is not saved

Comment: Can't be determined without a whole lot more information.

Comment: incognito mode helps with privacy, but not anonymity. Privacy and anonymity are two completely different things. To have a layer of protection against what your administrator sees, consider using the Tor web browser, https://tor.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I own the private WiFi.

Comment: your wifi device, as you know, can admit several users using it at once. If you let 5 different people use your wifi device regularly without blocking them, your internet service provider (ISP, which you are calling the device administrator for some reason) can assume that all traffic by these 5 people is your traffic. although they might be able to distinguish them from you by their MAC address (unique to each connecting device) like how you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device administrator, or whoever owns and provides the "private" WiFi, can see, and optionally log, the following:

- **MAC address** of the device you're connecting to the WiFi from. For example, if you're accessing the hotspot with a Samsung mobile device, the administrator would be able to see it in the first two characters of your MAC address, which often is displayed outright on the WiFi management software
- **IP address**, decided by the ISP the device administrator is subscribed to
- **Full website URLs** you are visiting if those websites are not secured by SSL
- **Second-level domains** (with their TLD) you visit (as opposed to full URL and webpage file/folders) in the case of websites secured by SSL (lock symbol). For example, they can know you are on `facebook.com` for every page you visit there, but not `facebook.com/janetjackson/12345.html`

How the above changes when **incognito mode** is activated is really specific and different between whichever devices and websites that offer the incognito mode. At best, incognito mode reduces user tracking which does not always mean hiding your IP address, but merely throwing less cookies at you so that your trail and online movements are followed less, which is not much of an improvement.

Incognito mode helps with **privacy**, but not **anonymity**. Privacy and anonymity are two completely different things. To have a layer of protection against what your administrator sees, consider using the **Tor web browser** if not VPN.